# Prove that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{+}$ is simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{+}$ is simply connected. I first write down the meaning of this set. It's equal to say ${z: z=re^{i\theta},0<\theta<2\pi}$ Then I let $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t), t \in [a,b]$ be a closed path in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{+}$. Then since it's closed, $z(a)=x(a)+iy(a)=z(b)$. Then according to the definition of a set being simply connected, I need to show that for any simple closed contour lying in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{+}$, its interior also lies in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{+}$. Then I don't know how to proceed my proof. Can anyone give me a hint please？Thanks so much!

Comment: A *path-connected* space is connected, so prove $\mathbf C - (0,\infty)$ is path connected, which is visually obvious.  Hint:  Have you heard the phrase "all roads lead to Rome"?  Treat $-1$ as Rome and use line segments with endpoint $-1$ as roads other than line segments on the positive real axis.

Comment: $\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R_+$ is homeomorphic to $(0,2\pi)\times(0,+\infty)$ hence [contractible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space)

Comment: Hi, KCd, is it sufficient to conclude simply-connected from path-connected? I think that we also need to show that it's contractible?

Comment: @WendyLyu No, not contractible necessarily. KCd was hinting a method by which you might show it is simply connected. There are simply connected but non-contractible spaces (e.g. the sphere $S^n$ for $n\ge2$)

Comment: Path connected does not imply simply connected. Contractible does.

Comment: Modifying Kcd's idea, show that every path can be continuously transformed to the path from -1 to -2. by taking the obvious interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

"I need to show that for any simple closed contour lying in $\mathbb{C}∖\mathbb{R}_+$, its interior also lies in $\mathbb{C}∖\mathbb{R}_+$."

For me it feels most visually intuitive to prove the contra-positive of this statement: for every simple closed contour $C$ in $\mathbb{C}$ whose interior contains a point outside of $\mathbb{C}∖\mathbb{R}_+$, *which is to say: contains a point in $\mathbb{R}_+$*, $C$ itself also contains a point in $\mathbb{R}_+$. This is visually quite clear I think.

Of course now the question is how to prove it, which ultimately depends on your definition of 'interior'. If, for instance, you happen to know that this interior is an open set $A$ such that $\overline{A} \backslash A = C$ (where the bar means topological closure), you can try to show that $\overline{(A \cap \mathbb{R}_+)} \backslash (A \cap \mathbb{R}_+)$ consists of at least two points, all of which belong to $C$ but at most one of which can be outside $\mathbb{R}_+$.